# Can I place an std::function's capturing lambda in my own memory?

Tags: c++, lambda, memory-management, c++17

I have a lambda I'm storing into an `std::function` to be called in a separate thread, that looks like this:

```
void * specialMalloc(size_t size);  // provides annointed memory; beloved by all

int n;
std::function f = [=]()mutable -> void {
    printf("%i", n); 
};
```

Is it possible to create a `std::function f` that takes this lambda and it's `int n`, and asks `specialMalloc()` to carefully prepare memory to place it into?  Specifically in C++17, where I've read custom allocators have been deprecated?

Comment: They were removed and not deprecated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way custom to pass allocator in the current C++. `std::function` will use global `operator new`. It will not even use class's operator `new`, instead calling the global one.

However `std::function` typically employs small object optimization. At least you expect it to engage for pointer-sized functors. Real implementations have buffer for small object optimization for 2-3 pointers, MSVC has much more. With small object optimization, `std::function` does not use indirect memory at all.

Your functor has a size of `int`, which is very likely to fit small object optimization. **You functor will not cause any allocation function to be called when it is put into `std::function`.**

For larger functors, you can make their data indirect, and allocate it on your own, so that they'll make use of small object optimization, and thus will not use the global operator `new`

There are other criteria for small object optimization to engage, specifically `noexcept` copy constructor, and not being overly alignend.

Unfortunately, there's no standard way to query in compile-time whether small object optimization apply, and it is not required by the standard (although recommended for some types of functors)

Comment: Thank you for your insight!  The memory my allocator prepares, only tries to keep allocations aligned to 64 bytes to prevent false-sharing, which is a problem with MSVC's global new; but if it's folding the data into the std::function object itself, then that works out well.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's not a good way to do this.

Well, `std::function` had a constructor that took a custom allocator but this functionality was [removed in C++17](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0302r0.html).

Comment: Per [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function) they were removed in C++17, not deprecated.